# Greenhouse Job Board API integration: HTTP Basic Auth over SSL/TLS

Tags: api, ssl, http-proxy, basic-authentication

I am building a job board using the Greenhouse API, getting a bit stuck on the last step of HTTP Basic Auth over SSL/TLS for the job application form data. Particularly the action="!!REQUEST MUST BE PROXIED ON YOUR SERVERS!!" bit below.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to implement this:

DESCRIPTION: The /applications method accepts a multipart form POST representing a job application. This method requires HTTP Basic Auth over SSL/TLS: the Basic Auth username is your API key (found on the API Credentials page), no password is required. A form which correctly represents the data required by this method would be constructed from the "questions" array available via the /job API method, this set of fields is job-specific (more details available in job method documentation).

```
https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/applications/

<!-- 
EXAMPLE FORM BELOW (simplified):

Please keep in mind that the HTTP Basic Auth API token is a secret key.  Any form posts should be proxied by your own servers.  Any direct post to the /applications POST method would reveal your secret key to anybody that views source--which would be a very bad thing.
-->
<form method="POST" action="!!REQUEST MUST BE PROXIED ON YOUR SERVERS!!" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <!-- represents the ID of the job -->
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="55555" />
  <!-- place the value of the gh_src URL parameter in the field below -->
  <input type="hidden" name="mapped_url_token" />
  <label>First Name <input type="text" name="first_name" /></label><br/>
  <label>Last Name <input type="text" name="last_name" /></label><br/>
  <label>Email <input type="text" name="email" /></label><br/>
  <label>Phone <input type="text" name="phone" /></label><br/>
  <label>Resume <input type="file" name="resume" /></label><br/>
  <label>Cover Letter <input type="file" name="cover_letter" /></label><br/>
  <label>LinkedIn Profile <input type="text" name="question_5555" /></label><br/>
  <label>Some dropdown
    <select name="question_3333">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
  </label><br/>
  <label>Multi select with checkboxes<br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="question_2222[]" value="2" /> Red</label><br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="question_2222[]" value="5" /> Orange</label>
  </label><br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: _“Must be proxied on your servers”_ means it is your server that has to make the POST request to their API. Have you researched how to do this in whatever language/framework you are using already?

Answer (score 4):

I built a custom Drupal module that's generating custom application form using Greenhouse Job Board API. I ended up doing the following:

1. I created a custom PHP library to work with the API.

   - https://github.com/minnur/GreenhouseJobBoardAPI
2. I used `$job = $greenhouse->getJob([JOB_ID], true);`. The second parameters indicates whether to return question fields or not.
3. I built the form using Drupal's form API and the returned question fields from the request above.
4. On form submit I took all the submitted variables and passed it to Greenhouse using PHP Curl Class.

   - https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class
5. For the Resume/Cover letter fields you will have to submit multipart data. Make sure your request headers contain: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=[YOUR_CUSTOM_BOUNDARY]`

   - [multipart/form-data php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676345/multipart-form-data-php-curl) (not a perfect example).
6. Post all data to `https://[API-KEY]@api.greenhouse.io/v1/applications/` via Curl.

Answer (score 2):

They are asking you to POST the form to your own server and have your server then POST to greenhouse. Otherwise you would need to include your secret and/or credentials in your rendered HTML in which case anyone could pick it up.

So your HTML form `action` attribute would be something like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/applications/new" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then you would need a server-side endpoint (Node, PHP, Ruby, Perl, etc.) that takes the form input from the browser and sends it to Greenhouse using a server-side POST.

For BASIC authentication you will include your credentials and/or secret as headers in the request.

When they mention that it must be "over SSL/TLS" that just means you must use "https" for the greenhouse API URL in your server-side code.

Comment: I believe I have the first bit working with an ajax post to PHP. Two things: I am not sure what to set for the dataType or contentType, as the application contains text fields along with pdf files. What would I need to do in PHP for a cross-origin post to the API at Greenhouse? I tried:
`$data = $_POST['firstName'];
$url = //greenhouse api url
function sendApplication() {
    http_post_data($url, $data);
}`
Which did not seem to work

Comment: Greenhouse employee here.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: If Company X posts a job and that ends up on Job Board Y, does the secret and/or credentials belong to Company X or Job Board Y? I'm assuming it's Job Board Y's, as otherwise Company X would have to provide the credentials to Job Board Y to keep on its servers.